# Python Dash graph legend covering x-axis labels

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

My Python web app has a Plotly Dash "Graph" whose legend covers the x-axis labels. I've tried adjusting the following elements, with no success and no visible changes at all:

1. legend style 'margin-top'
2. margin 'b'
3. padding 'b'

Here's the code:

```
    import dash
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html

    graph = dcc.Graph(
        figure = {
            'data': data, 
            'layout': dict(
                hovermode = "closest",
                height = 400, # 500 is a bit too big on a smartphone
                legend = dict(
                    font=dict(color='#7f7f7f'), 
                    orientation="h", # Looks much better horizontal than vertical
                    style={'margin-top': 100},
                ),
                font = {
                    'family': 'Segoe UI', 
                    'color': "#7f7f7f"
                },
                # Added more margin on the left side to fix the cutoff True/False labels on the booleans
                margin = dict(l=40, r=25, b=10, t=10),
                padding = dict(l=0, r=0, b=10, t=0),
            )
        }
    )
```

Here's what it looks like, showing the legend overlapping the x-axis labels:

[image: Chart showing overlapping legend]

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnBy6.png) in the documentation.

> y
>   Parent: layout.legend
>   Type: number between or equal to -2 and 3
>   Sets the y position (in normalized coordinates) of the legend. Defaults to "1" for 
>   vertical legends, defaults to "-0.1" for horizontal legends on graphs w/o range sliders and defaults to "1.1" for horizontal legends on graph with one or multiple range sliders.

It defaults to -0.1 **so I set it to -0.15**, which is a little bit lower, to give the x-axis labels some more room.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

graph = dcc.Graph(
    figure = {
        'data': data, 
        'layout': dict(
            hovermode = "closest",
            height = 400, # 500 is a bit too big on a smartphone
            legend = dict(
                font=dict(color='#7f7f7f'), 
                orientation="h", # Looks much better horizontal than vertical
                y=-0.15
            ),
        )
    }
)
```

Result:
[image: image showing problem solved]